# Calling a Python code inside PHP and displaying output

Tags: python, php

I've been struggling with PHP <-> Python interaction when trying to run a Python code inside a PHP plugin I have.

I've tried many different ways to call a Python code within my PHP, such as **escapeshellcmd/shell_exec** which provided only "print" outputs, without even being capable of inserting line breaks or other ways to display the data other than a continuous single line; also tried using **[pipes](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php)**, but got no output from that, don't know if I used it correctly though.

I just want to be able to call a Python code from my PHP Block, and display something like a graph or so as an output. Currently I'm only able to output the data from the DB i'm gathering it as a "print", which is kind of messy.

**edit:**

**PHP code** (the part i'm calling external python code):

```
$output = shell_exec('python /var/www/html/moodle/blocks/pibic/formulario.py');
if ($this->content !== null) {
  return $this->content;
}

$this->content         =  new stdClass;
$this->content->text   = $output;
```

**Python code:**

```
import MySQLdb

db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost",    # your host, usually localhost
                     user="user",         # your username
                     passwd="password",  # your password
                     db="moodle")        # name of the data base

# you must create a Cursor object. It will let
#  you execute all the queries you need
cur = db.cursor()

# Use all the SQL you like
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM mdl_pibic_form")

# print all the first cell of all the rows
for row in cur.fetchall():
    print row
```

This is the working code, with only "prints". As soon as I try to parse it into a simple table, printing "\n" chars inside the for, it doesn't apply to the output. I also tried calling simple graph plot codes (as simple as it could be) and no output was provided.

Comment: Can you put code you've tried ?

Comment: Sorry, just added them.

Comment: Try to programa the python script to encode the output into JSON. Would be easier get structural data in PHP.

Comment: I'll have a look into it, thanks.